# Checking if a string is overflowing from my view in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview, textview

I have a listview in Android which is dynamically loaded. The list view holds an image and on it is shows the description of the image which should ideally take up 20% of the images' height. How do I check if my textview which is on top of the image view in my list is taking a max height of 20% of the image?

[image]

As you can see from the screenshot, "Harvey's - -check in for a chance to win a free burger
Picker, ON" is fitting in the textview in 2 lines, sometimes if my android device is small it exceeds the background (black colored) view and looks bad. I need to stop that so I decided I must truncate the string if it overflows on my textview.

How do I truncate the strings on the textview so that once that 20% of the imageview height has been reached the image description ends with "..."

The xml I have at the moment is given below. Note that com.parse.myPackage.AspectRatioImageView is just a custom view for an imageview

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFFFF" >

<com.parse.myPackage.AspectRatioImageView
    android:id="@+id/campaignImageLabel"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/blank" />

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@color/fadedBlack">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/campaignNameLabel"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Loading..."
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textStyle="bold" />



</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/frameLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/campaignImageLabel"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:background="@color/fadedBlack">

        <TextView
        android:id="@+id/campaignLocationLabel"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:text="Location Loading..."
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this on your TextView

```
android:maxLines="2"
android:ellipsize="end"
```

This will truncate your text and place "..." at the end if it is longer than 2 lines

Comment: I did this, I am truncating the text after 2 lines, however I am missing the '...' at the end of the second line. Any ideas? My text used to fit EXACTLY 2 lines and the starting of the 3rd line was "and click here". my "and click here" is not being shown however there is no '...' before this

Comment: Problem solved, this was because my last word of the second line was a complete word, it didnt have to truncate that

Comment: The "..." won't show if the text fits in 2 lines. I'm guessing you are setting the "and click here" text in code and it is part of the same TextView. If this is the case, it would be a good idea to have a separate TextView for it with android:visibility="GONE". Then make it visible in your code when everything loads.

Answer (score 1):

You can use :

```
android:ellipsize="end" 
android:maxLines="1"
```

Change value of `maxlines` to check manually that what makes it 20% of your imageview's height. `ellipsize` will take care of the '...' termination.

Comment: I did this, it is truncating my text after 1 line, however I do not get '...' at the end as expected. I had "Hello my name is Akshat and" in first line and "I am here to talk to you" in the second line. The first line is getting truncated however now ... after the "Akshat and"

Comment: Problem solved, you were right, this was because of the last word of my 1st line being a complete word

Comment: @AkshatAgarwal Glad that i could help you and you should have marked this as an answer...

Comment: your answer was as correct as the other answer, however the other answer was answered 3 min before yours, therefore I marked him.